# CSS - <p> leaving a trail when sliding

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've a `<p>` tag and when it starts sliding from left to right it leaves a kind of trail through the screen. I've never seen anything like this before.

I'm animating it using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".choosenHero").animate({
 "right": "300px"
}, 3000);
});
```

and here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of odd "sliding" effect]

Comment: Have your tried to use another browser? It will be hard to help if we can't reproduce it.

Comment: It's probably just rendering wrong, the browser isn't clearing before rendering the next frame. Mr.doob made fun of this: http://www.mrdoob.com/#/128/internet_explorer_6

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hdJ32/

Comment: Is just the fault of the rendering engine. IE 11 is much better in rendering, just saying.

Comment: I can't see where you are using css3..? that is jquery.  if you use css3 it will be real smooth..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using simple CSS transitions rather than jquery. As jquery does animation by changing css properties and is not the same thing.

So use jquery to add a class which has the end state of say:

```
.moved{
    left: 300px;
}
```

and on the initial state of the paragraph use something like:

```
.moving-object{
    position:relative;
    transition: left 2s;
    left: 0px;
}
```