# CSS Page transition leaving a trail

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, styling

So previously I had been figuring out how to specify which transition activates when a specific page is selected, I figured it out.

Now....I'm curious why there is a trailing section of the previous page when I transition out of my selected effect. Upon each click, you'll notice a trailing, fading section of the previous page:

**Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzFjk**

If you take a look at the original page then you'll see what I'm going for:

**The goal**: [**tympanus.net**](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions) (go to *Choose a transition > Rotate > Room*)

---

There are many attributes such as the code below specifying the styling for rotateroomLeftOut and rotateRoomLeftIn...etc. But I've matched them exactly to the original code and it still doesn't look like.

```
    @-webkit-keyframes rotateRoomLeftOut {

to { opacity: .9; -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateRoomLeftOut {
    to { opacity: .9; -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateRoomLeftOut {
    to { opacity: .9; transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(90deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateRoomLeftIn {
  from { opacity: .3; -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateRoomLeftIn {
 from { opacity: .3; -moz-transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg); }
}
@keyframes rotateRoomLeftIn {
   from { opacity: .3; transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-90deg); }
}
```

Comment: how is it supposed to look then, do you have an example for the 'original' as well?

Comment: @myfunkyside http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/ **Choose a transition > Rotate > Room** sorry, I mentioned in a comment below I should of included it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an opacity in your keyframes which is causing the colors to "trail"

Removing the opacity from the keyframes seems to solve your problem:

```
@-moz-keyframes moveFromRight {
    from { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkcoH)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks...however I've messed around with that and figured that out. Sorry, should of mentioned. However, even if there's no opacity, there is still a trail after the main page content is settled.

If you take a look at the original page http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/ and goto **Choose a transition > Rotate > Room** then you'll see what I'm going for, and it still seems off. I'm going to add a fade to dark on the page that is transitioning out, but the trail is still the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it, the culprit: `pt-page-ontop`

In all your cases (54 to 57) this class was added (in JS) the the page that moves out...

```
case 54:
    inClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomLeftIn';
    outClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomLeftOut pt-page-ontop';
    break;
```

...I don't know why this doesn't have the same effect on the [tympanus-page](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/), but if I change it to this...

```
case 54:
    inClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomLeftIn pt-page-ontop';
    outClass = 'pt-page-rotateRoomLeftOut';
    break;
```

...it works without the trail.
(You still see a veil of the out-page disappearing, but notice that's also the case on the [tympanus-page](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/), but there the transitions are just faster so you don't really see it).

---

**Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dxwuk**

(BTW, your CodePen HTML had double html- and body-tags inside the body-tag, CodePen probably fixes that for you on rendering, but better check your code twice)

---

### UPDATE

If you combine [MathiasaurusRex' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24126717/3407923) with this one, you will lose that last veil as well. Fiddle around with that to see what you like best..

Comment: @ChrisWeigen - If this answer has helped you, could you please accept it, and if not, leave a comment why. That way, any other people with the same problem will know whether this will fix their issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the "same" problem months ago.
[CSS - <p> leaving a trail when sliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404364/css-p-leaving-a-trail-when-sliding)

Sadly I didnt find any good solution, i had to use a PNG image to solve it :(

Comment: As the background image?